# Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ diagonalizable matrix with characteristic polynomial, find the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, characteristic-functions

Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ diagonalizable matrix with characteristic polynomial

$a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0$,

Find the matrix

$a_nM^n+a_{n-1}M^{n-1}+...+a_1M+a_oI$,

where $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matix.

Please give me some hints.

Comment: Can you find that if $M$ is really a diagonal matrix? (note that then the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $M$)

Comment: Ever heard of Caley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: so is this correct ?
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        0 &0 & \cdots & 0
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: What has this to do with $M$ being diagonalisable?

Comment: I know $M$ being diagonalisable means $M = P^{-1} A P$

Comment: May be ?
 $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
        0 &0 & \cdots & \lambda_n
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Look at the second comment.

Answer (score 1):

If $p( \lambda )$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ then $p(A)=0$ for the Hamilton Cayley theorem